# Match multiline pattern in bash using Perl on macOS

Tags: regex, bash, macos, perl

On `macOS`, using built-in `bash`, I need to match two words on two consecutive lines within a file, say `myKey` and `myValue`.

Example file:

```
<dict>
    <key>myKey</key>
    <string>myValue</string>
</dict>
```

I already have a working command for *substituting* a value in such a pair using `perl`:

```
perl -i -p0e 's/(<key>myKey<\/key>\s*\n\s*<string>).+(<\/string>)/$1newValue$2/' -- "$filepath"
```

Question is, how do I simply find whether the file *contains* that key/value pair, without substituting anything, or, more to the point, just get to know, whether any substitution was made?

EDIT:

1. Within replacement pattern: `\1` -> `$1`.
2. Added clarification to the question.

Comment: Maybe by parsing it.  It look like XML to me, a syntax famously difficult to model in regex

Comment: Choose the right tool first. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: Regex `s/a/X/` changes `a` to `X`, while `m/a/` _matches_ `a` (well, tries to). Both by default work on `$_`. The match itself returns true/false, so you can do `say "yes" if /a/` (print yes if it matches `a`, so if there is an `a` in `$_`). You may leave off `m` with `/.../`. Then, if you add parens, `/(a)/` it also _captures_ (whatever it matched, `a` here) and returns that if called in _list context_. Btw, use `$1` (etc) in replacement, not `\1`

Comment: But if you want to just scan the file to see whether that pattern is there, drop that `-i` and change `-p` to `-n`. So `perl -0777 -nE'say "yes" if /your-pattern/' ...`. The `-0777` slurps the whole file, which is what your `-0` is used, but `-0` _can_ do something else in fact (even though it's unlikely)

Comment: Now, if you are going to work with this please at least skim through [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: @zdim Thanks for the pointers, mate.

Comment: Like I showed you. You can invert the usual `if(COND) { ... }` in Perl (not exactly always) and go `say "yes" if COND;` (don't even need parens around condition now).  So what I used, `say "yes" if /.../;` tests whether the regex matches (against `$_` by default, which is the currently read line in a one-liner), and if it did it prints `yes`.  (The `say` is `print` with newline. To enable it you need `use feature "say";`. In a one-liner, `-E` instead of `-e` enables all "feature"s.)  My second comment is the full one-liner; just put in `your-pattern` and files to process.

Comment: @zdim Sorry, didn't see your second comment at first. If you post `perl -0777 -nE 'say "yes" if /myKey\s*\n\s*myValue/' -- "$filepath"`, I will gladly accept that as an answer.

Comment: Oh, I see now (by your comment's edit). Thanks for the offer, but this may be a bit too basic to be considered generally useful on this site.  If I wrote up a little more it'd be a generic introduction to basic regex concepts; well, many nice ones have been written :). Glad it helped :))  Thank you again for offering to take care of that :)

Comment: @zdim I would argue, that my problem was more with the fact that if one doesn't know perl, it is not obvious how to extract a yes/no answer out of `perl` command (since it always returns 0 unless execution error occurs). In hindsight, I should’ve googled something like 'perl print statement' and 'perl if construct'. In any case, thank you again.

Comment: Well, it really isn't simple at all if you don't know the language; specially in a one-liner where a lot of language/syntax shortcuts are at work.

Comment: Come to think of it ... there is one other thing you can do: `exit` from that Perl program (one-liner) with a code that indicates whether there was a match or not.  So `perl -0777 -nE'exit( /.../ )' ...`.  So after this command the `$?` (in `bash`) will have a `1` if there was a match, or `0` if there wasn't.  Better yet, it seems that you want to do that substitution but only want to _also_ know whether anything was found ... in which case you can do the same, since `s/../../` operator returns the number of subs made. So `perl -i -p0e 'exit(s/.../.../)' ...`

Comment: Perhaps this would be good to write up (post) then, after all.  Please let me know whether that comment above makes sense -- is that better, that the bash script itself can check, and whether you'd want to substitute _and_ check?

Comment: @zdim And there it is, we’ve come down to the very root of the problem. It’s amazing what we can do with computers these days... The `exit(...)` part is perfect. I agree that a short write-up is warranted, if you have the time.

Comment: Yes, this is good to post now, I think.  I'll get to it in a bit.  If you think of anything else/more please update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the basic question you only need to change the substitution operator to the match operator, and print conditionally on whether it matches or not. This can also be done with substitution.

However, since this is in a `bash` script you can also `exit` from the perl program (one-liner) with a code that indicates whether there was a match/substitution; then the script can check `$?`.

To only check whether a pattern is in a file

```
perl -0777 -nE'say "yes" if /pattern/' -- "$file"
```

The `-0777`, that "slurps" the whole file (into `$_`), is safer than `-0` which uses the null byte as records separator. Also, here you don't want `-i` (change file *in place*) and want `-n` (loop over records) instead of `-p` (also prints each). I use `-E` instead of `-e` to enable (all) `feature`s, for `say`. See all this [in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).

Inside a shell script you can use the truthy/falsy return of the match operator in `exit`

```
perl -0777 -nE'exit(/pattern/)' -- "$file"
# now check $? in shell
```

where you can now programatically check whether the pattern was found in the file.

Finally, to run the original substitution *and* be able to check whether any were made

```
perl -i -0777 -pe'exit(s/pattern/replacement/)' -- "$file"
# now check $? in shell
```

where now the exit code, so `$?` in the shell, is the number of substitutions made.

Keep in mind that this does abuse the basic success/failure logic of return codes.

See [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for a regex tutorial.